# converting military time to standard time in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, datetime-conversion

This block of JS is a date formatting solution I found online and it works well, however it doesn't include a way to convert the time from military time to standard time and account for PM/AM differences. How can I add to this?

HTML

```
<ion-row>
            <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Date:</span>{{getFormattedDate(event.eventTime, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}}</ion-col>

<ion-col><span class="showDetails">Time:</span>{{getFormattedDate(event.eventTime, 'HH:MM')}}</ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">

        </ion-row>
```

.TS FILE

```
getFormattedTime (time, format) {
            var t = new Date(time);
            var tf = function (i) { return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i };
            return format.replace(/yyyy|MM|dd|HH|mm|ss/g, function (a) {
                switch (a) {
                    case 'yyyy':
                        return tf(t.getFullYear());

                    case 'MM':
                        return tf(t.getMonth() + 1);

                    case 'mm':
                        return tf(t.getMinutes());

                    case 'dd':
                        return tf(t.getDate());

                    case 'HH':
                        return tf(t.getHours());

                    case 'ss':
                        return tf(t.getSeconds());

                }
            })
        }// end of getFormattedTime
```

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment , it will save you from a lot of headaches. Just to give you an introduction, momentjs is the top js lib when you want to work with dates on js files and that repo provides you with that and a lot of pipes ready to go.

Comment: Did you try the angular2 date pipe? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html